# Filter dataframe column by one condition for one specific value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a dataframe on one specific datetime column. This is done by:

```
df = df[df['result_date'] >= "{yday} 10:30:00"]
```

The condition above is, to filter result_date by greater than yday at 10:30am UTC
However, the caveat to this filter is that it should apply this filter only where
`df['proc_date'] == day before yday.`

Basically, we have result_date column and proc_date column. The proc date has dates ranging from day before to yday and same for result date. What I need to do is:

```
index | proc_date |  result_date
  0     2021-09-05   2021-09-05 20:00:00
  1     2021-09-05   2021-09-06 10:29:00
  2     2021-09-05   2021-09-06 10:31:00
  3     2021-09-06   2021-09-06 10:00:00
  4     2021-09-06   2021-09-06 12:00:00
```

I need to filter out rows 0 and 1 where the result_date is < yday 10:30am UTC and proc_date is day before yday.

Any insight? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `&` to do boolean `and` during masking: `df[(condition_1) & (condition_2)]`

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
df = df[
    (df['result_date'] >= f"{yday} 10:30:00")
    & (df['proc_date'] == prev_day)
]
```

Comment: Right, thank you. The pandas DSL _does_ have interesting interactions with python order-of-operations. Life is full of tradeoffs.